# Unable to do dynamic pivoting in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot, dynamic-pivot

I need to do pivoting in SQL Server 2008 R2. I have an EMP table having employee records and then one Child table where related child records are stored.

Now I want to create one record per employee in output. I'm not sure how to place Child1Name, Child2Name, Child3Name .... Child99Name on column side. Below is sample input and output. TIA.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    /*
    My Sql server 2012
    the code below can run at above 2005
    */
    set nocount on
    ;with EmpTable as (
                        select * 
                        from (values(1,'John'),(2,'Tim'),(3,'Steve')) as a(ID,Name)
                      ),
           ChildTable as(
                         select * 
                         from (values(1,1,'Tina'),(2,1,'Mike'),(3,2,'Mona'),(4,3,'Zane'),(5,3,'Diana'),(6,3,'Marry')) as b(ID,EmpID,Name)
                        ),
           sourceData as(
                         select a.Name,b.EmpID,b.Name as ChildName,row_number() over(partition by EmpID order by B.ID,b.Name) as rn
                         from EmpTable as a inner join ChildTable as b on a.ID = b.EmpID

                        )
          select EmpID,Name,[1] as Child1Name,[2] as Child2Name,[3] as Child3Name
          from sourceData as  a pivot (max(ChildName) for rn in([1],[2],[3]))as b
    /*
    EmpID       Name  Child1Name Child2Name Child3Name
    ----------- ----- ---------- ---------- ----------
    1           John  Tina       Mike       NULL
    2           Tim   Mona       NULL       NULL
    3           Steve Zane       Diana      Marry
    */   



/*
Dynamic  pivoting
My Sql server 2012
the code below can run at above 2005
*/
--step 1 :
set nocount on
;with EmpTable as (
                    select * 
                    from (values(1,'John'),(2,'Tim'),(3,'Steve')) as a(ID,Name)
                  ),
       ChildTable as(
                     select * 
                     from (values(1,1,'Tina'),(2,1,'Mike'),(3,2,'Mona'),(4,3,'Zane'),(5,3,'Diana'),(6,3,'Marry')) as b(ID,EmpID,Name)
                    ),
       sourceData as(
                     select a.Name,b.EmpID,b.Name as ChildName,row_number() over(partition by EmpID order by B.ID,b.Name) as rn
                     from EmpTable as a inner join ChildTable as b on a.ID = b.EmpID

                    )
      select * into #a
      from sourceData 

--Step 2: 
      declare @PivotColumn as varchar(5000),@DisplayColumn as varchar(5000),@Sql as nvarchar(4000)
     ;with columnData as ( select distinct rn from #a)
      select  @PivotColumn = isnull(@PivotColumn,'')+quotename(cast(rn as varchar))+',',@DisplayColumn= isnull(@DisplayColumn,'')+quotename(cast(rn as varchar))+' as Child'+cast(rn as varchar)+'Name,'
      from columnData
      set @PivotColumn = left(@PivotColumn,len(@PivotColumn)-1)
      set @DisplayColumn = left(@DisplayColumn,len(@DisplayColumn)-1)
     set @Sql = 'select EmpID,Name,'+@DisplayColumn+' from #a as a pivot(max(ChildName) for rn in ('+@PivotColumn+')) as b'

     exec sp_executesql @sql
/*
EmpID       Name  Child1Name Child2Name Child3Name
----------- ----- ---------- ---------- ----------
1           John  Tina       Mike       NULL
2           Tim   Mona       NULL       NULL
3           Steve Zane       Diana      Marry
*/
```

Comment: Thanks, let me check this

Comment: Thanks it worked for this partial use case. Can you help little more here? I need to add Spouse as well in this fashion. One Emp may or may not have multiple spouse like child. Then how can we do that?

Comment: Change the inner join to left outer join

Comment: Spouse table is as good as Child table or consider it as replica of Child.. Then spouse name should also appear it like Spouse1Name, Spouse2Name etc...

Comment: Hi I'm still not able to do nesting pivoting. Can you please show some example code? That will be a good help.

Comment: /*the code below append the first example code  */
          pivoting as ( select EmpID,Name,[1] as Child1Name,[2] as Child2Name,[3] as Child3Name
                        from sourceData as  a pivot (max(ChildName) for rn in([1],[2],[3]))as b
                     )
          select * from pivoting /*copy pivot code*/